# Why is basic_fstream<unsigned char> order of magnitude slower than basic_fstream<char> on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, performance, file, io

In a program I was working on some one used alias for byte in the following way:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using Byte = unsigned char;

void write(const Byte* buffer, size_t size) {
    std::basic_fstream<Byte> file("1gb_file", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    file.write(buffer, size);
    file.flush(); // To ensure the data is being written, to eliminate caching claims
}

int main(){
    auto GB = 1024u * 1024u * 1024u;
    std::vector<Byte> zeros(GB, 0);
    write(zeros.data(), zeros.size());
    return 0;
}
```

The time this function took to execute on `Byte == unsigned char`: 52.0245s on my brand new SSD, MSVC-x64 on release mode.

On the other hand, if we change the definition to `Byte == char`: 1.46725s. That's it.

Why is this difference, and are there any general good practices on using the standard library to avoid such pitfalls?

Note(Edited due to a mistake): On Linux the code actually fails to run when given unsigned char(on gcc and clang), as @SergeyA pointed out. The GCC version on windows also fails to run, contrary to what I have written beforehand.

Comment: If you have Linux installed as the operating system I would actually like to know if that happens as well, because I've only tested this on VM and could not have replicated the bug, although this does not mean much (because "writing to disk" on a VM might write everything to RAM and flush it later).

Comment: On my Linux installation it doesn't work at all. `write` fails for `unsigned char` streams setting badbit on thje stream. As far as I can tell, internal implementation detail member (judging by the name, has to do with converting locales) is nullptr. Looks like unsigned char streams are not really mainstream.

Comment: Adding a check for `file.good()` then perror gives  `Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character` and nothing written to the file.  CHECK YOUR RETURN CODES.

Comment: @stark You are correct, but that happens only on Linux, I have fixed the post accordingly. The Windows version works just fine though. I actually did not manage to get that error , I got a the same error as SergeyA.

Comment: Actually that was Windows under Cygwin, not Linux.

Comment: Well yeah I meant also GCC on windows, as I've written at the end of the question itself..

Answer (score -1):

I am going to bite the bullet here and guess that it has to do with locales. Based on very limited information I have, it looks like in MSVC unsigned char streams to perform locale conversions, while normal char streams do not and instead just do bulk IO. (See Notes on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write).

Interestingly enough, the same code snippet doesn't work at all on my Linux installation with g++ 5.4 (rather old, I know). Write fails due to some internal member in stream class being nullptr (whoever interested it is _M_codecvt) and stream's `badbit` is set.

Comment: I compiled and ran on my VM running on linux (ubuntu 16.04, on both clang and gcc), it worked in about the same speed. I also thought about conversions when first encountered this bug but I don't know that this is the case, converting a pointer of `unsigned char` to `char` is very cheap, and converting each value individually sounds like a really stupid implementation.

Comment: @Michael, I think, you misunderstand the conversion. It is not conversion of the pointers, it is conversion of characters! converting locales allow converting one (sequence of) characters to another. I am 80% sure this is what is happening here. By the way, I now suspect that you think you need to use `std::fstream<unsigned char>` to store data blob of `unsigned char`. This is totally **not** the case.

Comment: Write also fails for me with `Byte=unsigned char` using linux g++ 7.2.0

Comment: @SergeyA I wrote "and converting each value individually sounds like a really stupid implementation", I did consider that. 

You obviously don't need `std::basic_fstream<unsigned char>` to store that, you can just cast the pointer which is the right thing to do. Actually I've had a mistake in my Linux version that caused the code to run at the same time, you are actually correct, the code is invalid for unsigned char under gcc, that is very wierd.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I've updated a few stuff that I got wrong, I did not check for the fail bit and got things wrong actually. Now that it behaves wierd on Linux we only have more stuff to explain.

Comment: Use `char` for the `fstream`, open the stream in `binary` mode, and type-cast your `Byte*` pointer to `char*` when passing it to `write()`, eg: `std::ofstream<char> file("1gb_file", std::ios::binary); file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer), size);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Obviously I would do that but this does not answer the question